# i have my eror in android studio (flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

hi this is my eror and this is my code plzzz help me :)

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#51d6d relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'

my code:

```
Container(
          height: 80,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            itemCount: categories.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return categoriesTile(
                title: categories[index].CategorieName,
                imgUrl: categories[index].ImageUrl,
              );
              }),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

add width property

width: double.infinity

```
Container(
          height: 80,
          width: double.infinity
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            itemCount: categories.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return categoriesTile(
                title: categories[index].CategorieName,
                imgUrl: categories[index].ImageUrl,
              );
              }),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

`categoriesTile` is causing an issue. I think it must be a `Row`. The solution is to provide a fixed `width` to it.

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: 100, // Give some width here. 
    child: categoriesTile(...),
  );
}
```

If you want to give it full screen width, then replace above `width` with the following:

```dart
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `Listview` with `Expanded` widget. checkout the below code for help.

```
Container(
                height: 80,
                child: Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                      itemCount: categories.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        return categoriesTile(
                          title: categories[index].CategorieName,
                          imgUrl: categories[index].ImageUrl,
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              )
```